# Vue: Header Navigation in App.vue but modifed in Different views?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Ive been stuck on the best way to manage a header navigation in Vue 2, vuex with VueRouter.
I have a main 'header' type navigation in my App.vue

```
    <div id="nav">
      <!--Try and create a dynamic nav-->
      <span v-for="route in routes" :key="route.to">
        <router-link :to="`${route.to}`">{{route.text}}</router-link> |
      </span>
    </div>
    <b-container>
      <router-view />
    </b-container>
  </div>
```

I was hoping as, the user navigates around the page and into other views and components within views. That i could update the 'routes' array to push the current location they are in. Obviously this is very Non Vue since it would require a global variable of some sort. I was curious if the best way to go about updating a header nav when you are working with nested routes.

Example of routes:

```
  {
    path: '/Teams',
    name: 'Teams',
    component: Teams
  },
  {
    path: '/:teamName/Athletes',
    name: 'Athletes',
    component: Athletes
  },
  {
    path: '/:teamName/Athletes/:id',
    name: 'Athlete',
    component: Athlete
  }
```

What i would like is for when you are on the Athlete page, you could have a route back to athletes ON the App.vue header nav, that is dynamic with the selected :teamName. That could be removed and added as necessary.

Example of user story: /Teams-> Selects team 'Team1' -> Sends them to /Team1/Atheltes -> clicks an athlete -> sends them to /Team1/Athlete/1.  In the header nav (Which is cucrently in App.vue) how can i add a router-link to include the appropriate ':teamName' to be able to go back to /Team1/Athletes?

Comment: Are You using Vuex?

Comment: @Borjante yes I am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to use Vuex will simplify your work:

Put your routes on a state:

```
// ...
state: {
  routes: [{
    path: '/Teams',
    name: 'Teams',
  }]
}
```

/Teams-> Just remove others routes that can be added.

```
// ...
mutations: {
  deafultRoute(state, payload) {
    state.routes = state.routes.slice(0, 1); // Be sure to have only 1 route
  }
}
```

/Team1/Atheltes -> Add the team route for team:

```
// ...
mutations: {
  addTeamRoute (state, payload) {
    state.routes = state.routes.slice(0, 2); // Be sure to have only 2 routes
    let newPAth = {
      path: `/${payloadteamName}/Athletes`,
      name: 'Athletes'
    }
    state.routes[1] = newPAth 
  }
}
```

/Team1/Athlete/1. -> Add the team route for team:

```
// ...
mutations: {
  addAthleteRoute (state, payload) {
    state.routes = state.routes.slice(0, 3); 
    let newPAth = {
      path: `/${payload.teamName}/Athletes/${payload.id}`,
      name: 'Athlete'
    }
    state.routes[2] = newPAth 
  }
}
```

I think you don´t need to save `Component` on routes array.

Comment: I was just thinking of adding to its own state, but was unsure if that was the best practice. It seems to fit nicely though, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do something like this:

```
{
    path: '/Teams',
    name: 'Teams',
    component: Teams,
    meta: {
      module:'Teams'
    }
  }
```

You can then use the meta property to direct your "back" (among other things)

Comment: Im not sure im fully following. If in route: /:teamName/Athletes/:id. How do i modify the nav in the App.vue file to add the appropriate route based on the teamName? Ill add more to my question to make this more clear. Thank you for the response!